# Rails - Is having an EACH loop inside a hash doable somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@items.each_with_index do |item, i|

  @mylist << {
    :id => item.id,
    :name => name.id,
    :users => {
      item.participations.each do |participant|
        :participant_image_link => participant.imagelink
      end
    }


  }

end

render :json => { :result => 'success', :mylist => @mylist }
```

I need the ability for an array for :users but can't figure out how to build it without breaking Rails.

Thanks

Comment: What should be the result of this? You'd be overwriting the `:participant_image_link` key every time you went through the loop even if such a thing worked. Perhaps you want an array of hashes instead?

Comment: @Chuck, I'd like :participants => item.item_participations but that breaks. So I thought about building it manually. With that I get error's: {"conversationlist":[{"id":187,"name":"QA - 4 Teammembers","participants":[{"item_participation":{"created_at":"2010-12-21T09:31:30-08:00","updated_at":"2010-12-21T09:31:30-08:00","participant_id":187}, {another participants.....}}], next item

Comment: Some how it breaks the rest of the hash and in the browser I get back: ,{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]} after the first record, instead of itterating through all the item records and including an array of their participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:users => item.participants.map { |participant|
  { :participant_image_link => participant.imagelink }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: That is amazing!!! You are my hero. Is there any way to add an index, I want to make sure participant is a MAX of 3

Comment: You can use anything in `Enumerable` (http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable) and you can implement your own methods. You can for example do `item.participants.take(3).map`.

Comment: You may also want to replace the each_with_index with map and assign the result into @mylist since i didnt see you use the index i anywhere.